# how to correctly append elements to collapsible div in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

so i am trying to append elements to collapsible div

i call the data from the database, then add it to the div

```
function loadItems(tx,result){
var htmlString;
var len = result.rows.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    htmlString+='<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"><h3> '+ (i+1) +'-'+ result.rows.item(i).emp_name +'</h3>';
htmlString+='<p> per hour:'+result.rows.item(i).emp_right+'</br> Per extra hour:'+result.rows.item(i).emp_addedright+' </p></div>';


}

$('#emplist').html(htmlString).collapsibleset().trigger('create');
```

}

it works  fine but for some reason it shows the word  "undefined" in top before the elements

i am assuming i have done something wrong but what?!

[image: scrreenshot from android emulator]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is happening, but you can solve it by destroying the collapsibleset widget, adding the collapsibles and then reinitializing the widget:

```
$('#emplist').collapsibleset("destroy").html(htmlString).collapsibleset().enhanceWithin();
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1q4aj484/)**

Comment: did not work in the emulator, still says "undefined"